# How to use picture element for sharp images on mobile

Tags: html, css, image

Picture element is getting widely and quickly spread (http://caniuse.com/#search=picture), and I think it is a great way to avoid serving oversized/undersized pictures, specially when you want to display the same picture on mobile and desktop at 100% of the viewport width.

That can be solved like this:

```
<img
    srcset="large.jpg  1920w, 
            medium.jpg  720w,
            small.jpg   360w"
    src="medium.jpg">
```

This allows the browser to be clever and decide which picture to load, but I find a problem with this approach: many mobile devices have a pixel density of 2 or more! Therefore when displaying it for 360w we would actually need the medium image if we want that image to look sharp. It could be done like this:

```html
<picture>
   <source srcset="http://goo.gl/LsuU9t" media="(min-width: 720px)">
   <source srcset="http://goo.gl/LsuU9t" media="(min-width: 360px and min-resolution: 2dppx)">
   <img src="http://goo.gl/LsuU9t">
</picture>
```

The problem here, in my opinion, is that this can grow as much as screen resolution grows and we lose the benefits of browser cleverly deciding the best option.

**So, my question is if there is a halfway point between the two, so I can still separate between html and css.**

Comment: Can You Run this code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Ivinraj Why? He provided an SO snippet, which works just fine. It is also not about the code here but about how to best use the picture element. To the OP: you might want to use placeholder images from something like placeholder.it to provide a great example, but I think this is a well asked question.

Comment: I added the snippet anyway

Comment: My server call to retrieve images takes a width parameter.

Answer (score 5):

The browser takes the pixel density into account when selecting an image. So a device with 360 CSS px wide viewport and a 2x pixel density would select medium.jpg. This is exactly what the `w` descriptor and the `sizes` attribute are designed to solve! Don't use `picture` here.

Also see https://ericportis.com/posts/2014/srcset-sizes/

Comment: Yes, it seems to do something with the pixel density but look here: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/ZbOMNR,  notice that with 319 pixel wide viewport, it is loading the medium img, not the  small one for 1x screens and large one for 2x screens. (in Chrome at least)

Comment: I get small for 1x and medium for 2x. Do you have "Disable cache" checked in the network pane?

Comment: Yes, yes I do. You are using Chrome developer tools, right?

Comment: Yes. Version 47.0.2516.0 canary (64-bit).

Comment: If you're testing the narrow viewport with device emulation, there are some bugs around that that were fixed (possibly causing the different result you're seeing), and some bugs that still need to be fixed

Comment: @YoavWeiss, not really, my phone is picking the big one and should be picking the medium one